# SMOF transition to the Redux Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, syntax-error

I try to make the transfer of a WordPress theme options from SMOF to the Redux Framework since SMOF is no longer maintained. I have successfully transferred all other options and they work perfectly but I have trouble in following context, getting this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'`

The old code was used to create a built-in translator option using `"type"  => "text"`, and has works great but no I do not know how to implement it in the new Redux Framework to run and no longer occur this error.

**Here's the old code from the SMOF Framework:**

```
$translate_strings = theme_get_translate_options();

foreach ( $translate_strings as $string_key => $string ) {

    $of_options[] = array( "name"  => esc_html( $string['string_text'] ),
        "id" => 'td_'.$string_key,
        "type"  => "text",
        );
}
```

**And here is the new interface of Redux Framework. where are supposed to implement the old code using** : `"type"  => "text",` :

```
$translate_strings = theme_get_translate_options();

// -> START Translation Info Fields
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Translator', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'id'         => 'translator-info-subsection',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(

        array(
            'id'       => '',
            'type'     => 'text',
            'title'    => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            'desc'     => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
            ),

        )
    ) );
```

**The code that I used and makes the errors occurs is the following:**

```
$translate_strings = theme_get_translate_options();

Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Translator', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'id'         => 'translator-info-subsection',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => array(

        foreach ( $translate_strings as $string_key => $string ) {
            array(
                'id'       => 'td_'.$string_key,
                'type'     => 'text',
                'title'    => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                ),
        }

        )
    ) );
```

I'm completely stuck on this and any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can't have a foreach inside an array ... can you construct an array for $fields prior to the Redux::setSection call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little reorganization should be enough:

```
$translate_strings = theme_get_translate_options();
$myFields = array();

        foreach ( $translate_strings as $string_key => $string ) {
            $myFields[]=
            array(
                'id'       => 'td_'.$string_key,
                'type'     => 'text',
                'title'    => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                );
        }
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'title'      => __( 'Translator', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'desc'       => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
    'id'         => 'translator-info-subsection',
    'subsection' => true,
    'fields'     => $myFields
    ) );
```

I took out your `foreach` from the initialization and initialized the `array` separately.

Comment: Thanks @LajosArpad ! Your code make sense but I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' ` on the last comma after parenthese:  `'title'    => __( '', 'redux-framework-demo' ),
                ),
        }`  What can be wrong? Can you edit your code? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexandruAndreiCostache, multumesc for pointing that out, I mistakenly left the comma at the end of the assignment, a semicolon is needed instead. Mersi pentru intelegere.

Comment: @Arpad brilliant! Works great! Thank you. Eu iti multumesc, mi-ai salvat ziua! :)