# SMOF migration to the Redux Framework in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redux

I am reviewing the following:

[SMOF transition to the Redux Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349231/smof-transition-to-the-redux-framework)

And am wondering if anyone might have any insight what the steps might be before all of this? What do you do with the Redux Config file once you get it? Just toss it in a plugins folder? I am trying to update an old WP site that was using SMOF and have installed both the Redux Framework and the Redux Converter plugin and can see that is appears to process the data appropriately but am unable to find any instructions what to do with the config file once I get it.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as this is probably a decade old problem so there is no active support regarding this anymore that I can find.

On this page:

https://github.com/syamilmj/Options-Framework

It seems where I am stuck is with the following paragraph:

*If you've already tested Redux and want to make the switch, open the Convert to Redux section. You'll be provided with a class that not only instantiates the new Redux-powered panel, but will also migrate any existing data with the activation or upgrade of your theme.*

Then in RefuxFramework.config.php which is the converted SMOF to Redux export, the beginning code looks as follows...

```
        if ( !class_exists( "ReduxFramework" ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !class_exists( "Redux_Framework__42b27b211d65ba651eb625b" ) ) {
        class Redux_Framework__42b27b211d65ba651eb625b {
            public function __construct( ) {

                // Your base config file for Redux
                add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array($this, 'loadConfig') );
                
                // Data migration
                add_action("after_switch_theme", array($this, "migrate_old_data"), 10 ,  2);    
                
            }

            public function loadConfig() {

                $sections = array (
            array (
                'title' => 'General Settings',
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Since the actions in that class run on `after_setup_theme`, you could toss it in a plugin for sure - you may even consider making it a "must use" plugin so it always loads. You could also add it as an `include` in your functions.php where it will load the class from your Theme. If your theme depends on Redux, you may just want to package it with the theme itself.

Comment: I must be missing a step. I tried adding the config file as an MU plugin and in  the plugin directory it was loading and not causing any errors but it appears that no conversion has taken place. To initiate a conversion it says to re-activate the theme which I adid and still nothing. In the conversion panel there is an Add Data Migration toggle set to on, and it says "A function will be provided which will, on theme activation/upgrade, migrate your data to your new Redux opt_name location denoted above. This makes it super easy to convert" The opt_name being redux_converter. What am I missing?